# What types of operands can be compared with <= etc. in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is it documented anywhere for which types of `a` and `b` I can call `a < b`?

Comment: </>/<=/>= is fairly incomprehensible, since one might easily parse `<` and `>` as a bracket pair... it's too bad we can't put markdown in the title.  maybe [<] / [>] / [<=] / [>=]  would be better?  It's still crazy but at least my eyes see what's going on.

Comment: Have you read [the MDN page on JavaScript comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#comparison_operators)? TypeScript doesn't affect those operators.

Comment: @JeffBowman I interpret the question as asking about TypeScript issuing compiler warnings and not about the operation of JavaScript runtime.

Comment: So I'm researching this... [the outdated language spec](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/136f728bb011ecf1bbf0ff2aac6dacc5cb6568cb/doc/spec.md#4193-the--------and--operators) says you can compare any two values if one's type is assignable to the other.  This is mostly what I see in my experiments but since then things have changed, like `--strictNullChecks` which gets angry about either one being possibly nullish.  Not sure if that suffices for an answer here. I'll keep looking

Comment: More info: apparently unconstrained type parameters can be compared, but this is considered a bug as per [ms/TS#50603](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50603).  Some work has gone into rationalizing the behavior of such operators, at [ms/TS#52807](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/52807) but it hasn't been merged and I'm not sure it will be.  @AlexeyRomanov Does the info in this and the previous comment constitute a full answer? If so I'll write it up. If not, what am I missing about the question?

Comment: @JeffBowman Obviously it doesn't affect them at runtime. But it's a TypeScript error to write e.g. `"2" < 12` which is literally an example given at that page.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it does.

Comment: @jcalz Also changed the title, hopefully this one is clearer.